# Camelot-py - Changing the matplotlib figure size on the camelot.plot method

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, python-camelot

When running camelot-py method camelot.plot() to plot grid lines of the pdf, the output is too small to read. [image]

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='165', flavor='stream', 
                          flag_size=True, table_areas=['65, 760, 600, 60'], 
                          columns= ['70.1, 152.9, 236.8, 287.7, 324.9, 351.9, 387.0, 423.2, 456.8, 487.9, 514.3, 559.9'])
print(tables[0].parsing_report)
camelot.plot(tables[0], kind ='grid').show()
```

The resulting plot is always the same size, super small 2"x2.5" tall. Ive tried passing matplotlib commands for figsize:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5, 11))
```

before the camelot.plot call but then I just get this <Figure size 612x792 with 0 Axes> before the camelot plot output.

Answer (score 1):

Try [set_size_inches](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches):

```
fig = camelot.plot(tables[0], kind ='grid')
fig.set_size_inches(14, 30)
fig.show()
```

Also sometimes it is useful to change axes ticks too:

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(0, 600, 20)
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(xs)
# ax.set_yticks(ys)
fig.show()
```